# Filtering jsonData in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json Response like below. From the response I need to filter "data" where "affiliation" has deptId=1. The json Response is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [{
            "id": 4,
            "userId": 11,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "deptId": 1,
                    "active": true,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "deptId": 2,
                    "active": true,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "userId": 6,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                "id": 5,
                "deptId": 1,
                "active": true,
                "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "userId": 11,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                "id": 6,
                "deptId": 1,
                "active": true,
                "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

To filter on the basis of active status, I would do something like:

```
snapshot.data['data'].where((data)=>data['active']==true)).toList()
```

What would be the syntax of the mentioned problem?

Comment: Hello could you explain better the result items that you expect to get? All the users who have at least an affiliate with deptId==1 or something else? Thank you

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. I need "data" where affiliation is to deptId 1. But nevermind. I made modifications on server side [added a key depts which contains id of all the affiliated departments and checked if data.depts contains 1]. and it is working.

Comment: I am glad you solved it; if you want to check this: List list = snap["data"].where((d) {
                        return d["active"]==true && d["affiliations"].any((dd)=>dd["deptId"]==1);
                        }).toList();
                      list.forEach((el)=>print("${el["userId"]}"));

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I figured that out just recently and have implemented the exact syntax for other same problem. I was about to post that answer here.

Answer (score 3):

For reference purposes I will write here 2 working methods to filter on lists without using for loops.

```
import 'dart:convert';

final String body = """
  {
    "success": true,
    "data": [{
            "id": 4,
            "userId": 11,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "deptId": 1,
                    "active": true,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "deptId": 2,
                    "active": true,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "userId": 6,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                "id": 5,
                "deptId": 1,
                "active": true,
                "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "userId": 11,
            "active": true,
            "affiliations": [{
                "id": 6,
                "deptId": 1,
                "active": true,
                "createdAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-04-28T05:28:12.065Z"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
  """;

void main() {
  Map snap = jsonDecode(body);

  List data = snap["data"];

  /*
  Find all items that have at least 1 subitem with deptId==1
  Output is: 11, 6, 11
  */
  List list1 = data
      .where((d) =>
          d["active"] == true &&
          d["affiliations"].any((dd) => dd["deptId"] == 1))
      .toList();
  list1.forEach((el) => print("${el["userId"]}"));

  /*
  Find all subitems which have deptId==1
  Output is: 3, 5, 6
  */
  List list2 = data
      .where((d) => d["active"] == true)
      .toList()
      .map((d) => d["affiliations"]
          .map((aff) => aff)
          .toList()
          .where((dd) => dd["deptId"] == 1)
          .toList())
      .toList();
  list2.forEach((el) => print(el[0]["id"]));

}
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I already figured that out after some trial and error. It is working for now. But it is nice that someone else with same problem will be able to solve easily now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how is your app structure but I usually use if else to show only data I want to show, for example if I use a listview builder I added something like this before my Container or Text widget;

```
snapshot.data[index].affiliations.deptId == 1 ?
Text(snapshot.data[index].affiliations.id.toString()) 
: Text("")
```

Or you can make a new list from your data. Just as example:

```
var filteredList = snapshot.data.where((i) => i.affiliations.deptId == 1).toList();
```

Comment: In this case, I am not using listview. So I don't have index of the items. I could use for loop and compare and add to the list but I am looking for a cleaner solution. Like using snapshot.data.data.where clause. This solution doesn't work because affiliations itself is an array and without passing index to affliations, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think only way to solve this without a loop could be filter on the server side, such as a method similar firebase or firestore equalTo() query method but I assume it's not an option for your case, or maybe you can try a loop in future function,..